# If XSLT or XQuery can Query Subtrees

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, css-selectors, xquery

Say I have a tree like this (but really, there are thousands of nodes like an HTML document):

```
                               a
                   ____________|____________
                  |                         |
                  b                         f
      ____________|                     ____|____
     |            |                    |         |
     c            m                    x         y
 ____|____      __|__                            |
|  |   |  |    |     |                           w
d  e   r  s    q     u
          |
          t
```

And I want to query for a subtree using this sort of "tree regular expression" (where * means skip over the node, and the letters are node labels or tags):

```
 __           __          __                                    __ 
/               \        /                                        \
|        a      |        |      a           a             a       |
|      /   \    |        |    /   \         |           /   \     |
|      b   f    |        |    b   f         z           *   f     |
|      |        |   OR   |    |       AND       AND   /   \  \    |  
|      c        |        |    x                       n   o   w   | 
|    /   \      |        |                            |           |      
|    d   e      |        |                            p           |    
\__           __/        \__                                    __/
```

Wondering if XSLT, XQuery, XPath, CSS selectors, or anything like that can perform such a query. If so, how it would be done at a high level. I just wrote up this example real quick without really considering if it would work well, so maybe if it difficult just being able to try part of this query such as the first block or the last block.

**Update**

This is pretty much the same image in an example HTML document:

```
<a>
  <b id="foo">
    <c>
      <d id="bar"></d>
      <e></e>
      <r></r>
      <s>
        <t></t>
      </s>
    </c>
    <m>
      <q></q>
      <u></u>
    </m>
  </b>
  <f id="baz">
    <x></x>
    <y>
      <w></w>
    </y>
  </f>
</a>
```

And this would be the pattern to match it with:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <d></d>
      <e></e>
    </c>
  </b>
  <f></f>
</a>
```

And this would be the output:

```
<a>
  <b id="foo">
    <c>
      <d id="bar"></d>
      <e></e>
    </c>
  </b>
  <f id="baz"></f>
</a>
```

Or this, either one:

```
<a>
  <b id="foo">
    <c>
      <d id="bar"></d>
      <e></e>
    </c>
  </b>
  <f id="baz">
    <x></x>
    <y>
      <w></w>
    </y>
  </f>
</a>
```

Comment: So you want selector to return you new tree from existed? For instance, `x` is not a child node of `b` from first tree, but you want XPath/CSS selector to return you tree where `x` is a child of `b`, right?

Comment: Don't think quite that. I would like for the XPath/CSS to return me the subtree from the first image that matches any one of the trees in the second image. The first picture is the full tree, the second picture is the query trees. If it doesn't match then it won't return anything.

Comment: Hmm...OK. So regarding first "subtree" you want selector to return you `a` node in case *it contains `f` child and `b` child that has `c` child that has `d` and `e` children* and so on...?

Comment: So for the `a,b,c,d,e,f` image in the second picture, I want it to return the actual nodes that match those tags in the first picture (the first picture matches that).

Comment: So not only `a`  node, but all 6 nodes in case structure is matched? I'm not sure, but it looks like an X-Y problem. Can you share more realistic example (real HTML/XML DOM sample) and your exact desired output?

Comment: Okay I added an example, thank you.

Comment: Your desired output is actually modified initial DOM. Neither CSS selector nor XPath can do that... Both can only locate nodes, but not transform one DOM-tree into another. In case of XML, you need XSLT.

Comment: Okay I updated the question to be about XSLT then, thank you.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are looking for, the pattern match syntax used in XSLT is a subset of XPath, you can find the formal syntax and examples in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#patterns for the XSLT 3 (latest version of the language since 2017), in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#patterns for XSLT 2 (second version of the language defined in 2007) and in https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#patterns for the first version XSLT 1 defined in 1999.

Comment: You can certainly select or match something like `/a[b[c[d and e]] and f]` but as you have been told, your result requires a transformation and it is not clear to me how you expect a single pattern to translate into a transformation, normally you would then write templates to make sure that certain nodes are copied at a certain levels and others are skipped (by processing only child nodes) or a removed (by matching them with an empty template).

Comment: XSLT can also as XML be generated by XSLT and in XSLT even then, in XSLT 3 using `fn:transform`, directly be executed, so it might be possible to solve that by transforming your "pattern" tree into XSLT and then execute that, but it is not an easy task and the rules you want are not clearly specified I think so I am not sure that approach will meet your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFo/1 I have tried to implement the suggestion made in a comment, that is, to use XSLT 3 to transform your shown "pattern" tree (provided as a parameter) into an XSLT 3 stylesheet that is then applied to the original input tree you have shown using the XPath 3.1 `transform` function, the XSLT is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform-alias"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="pattern-tree">
      <a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <d></d>
      <e></e>
    </c>
  </b>
  <f></f>
</a>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:variable name="stylesheet">
      <axsl:stylesheet version="3.0">
          <axsl:mode on-no-match="deep-skip"/>
          <axsl:template match="{string-join($pattern-tree//*!string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/name(), '/'), ' | ')}">
              <axsl:copy>
                  <axsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
              </axsl:copy>
          </axsl:template>
          <axsl:template match="@*">
              <axsl:copy/>
          </axsl:template>
      </axsl:stylesheet>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$stylesheet"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="transform(map { 'source-node' : /, 'stylesheet-node' : $stylesheet })?output"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output there is (for debugging and explanation it contains the generated XSLT but you can of course remove/comment out the `<xsl:copy-of select="$stylesheet"/>`)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
   <xsl:mode on-no-match="deep-skip"/>
   <xsl:template match="a | a/b | a/b/c | a/b/c/d | a/b/c/e | a/f">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:copy/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
<a>
   <b id="foo">
      <c>
         <d id="bar"/>
         <e/>
      </c>
   </b>
   <f id="baz"/>
</a>
```